# online tfs connection TF1003

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

i am use online tfs long ago(nearly 1 year)

i know it...it was work very well but
suddenly we get problem with conenction online tfs
error is
TF1003:Either you have not entered the necessary credintials or your user account to the team foundation server
  at blgsyrmhnds.tfspreview.com .Ask your server administrator to add the appropriate permissions to your account.Retry
[image]

when i try sign in again and again it load a form but that form does not close automatically and it still loading.......

in below you can see that form when i sign in..

[image]

when i close form manuel it give that error

TF1003:Either you have not entered the necessary credintials or your user account to the team foundation server
  at blgsyrmhnds.tfspreview.com .Ask your server administrator to add the appropriate permissions to your account.Retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only due to the tfspreview.com URL being decommissioned. Over a year ago Microsoft moved to tfs.visualstudio.com and I guess the old URL has finally been ditched. If you Update your URL to be blgsyrmhnds.visualstudio.com you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

is this just a case of tfspreview.com being withdrawn and a paid for service being introduced?
I can't find any details but I'm sure there has been a grace period where you could move from the free service to the paid for service. I would check whether your free service has ended.

update found this [blog](http://blog.devmatter.com/migrate-from-visual-studio-online-to-on-premises-tfs/) while looking for something else, looks as though you had until 20th May 2014 to get your data out.

Answer (score 0):

as i described [that developer community](http://yazilimsozluk.com/online-tfs-de-tf1003-baglanti-hatasi)
there is problem with microsoft...i replace preview.com with visualstudio.com and it works